# How to get a conformal factor between the Poincare Disk's metric and the Euclidean Metric?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

[Conformal Factor.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882024/conformal-factor-between-euclidean-metric-and-metric-on-poincar%C3%A9-ball-of-arbitra)

As you see in the linked post, the conformal factor is $\frac{2}{1-\left\|x \right\|^2}$.

But I'm more interested in how the outcome turns out. According to what I've heard, this may be demonstrated by comparing the lengths of tangent vectors.

Length of a tangent vector:

> Let $D$ denote the Poincare Unit Disk.
>
> Given a smooth map $\zeta :[-\epsilon,\epsilon]\to D$ with $\zeta (0)=\zeta _0$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}|_{t=0}\zeta (t)=\eta$, the length of the tangent vector $\eta$ in a metric $d$ is given by $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}|_{t=0}d(\zeta_0,\zeta(t))$.

I'm not sure how to set up the equation that compares the lengths of the tangent vectors to calculate the conformal factor. Can I get some help?

Lecture Note Definition of $D$:

Let $\Pi : H \to D = \{\zeta \in \mathbb{C}| |\zeta|<1\}$ s.t $\Pi (x,y,z) \mapsto \frac{x+iy}{1+z}$.

$\Pi^{-1}:\mathbb{C} \to H$ is defined by $\zeta \mapsto \left ( \frac{2\zeta}{1-|\zeta|^2},\frac{1+|\zeta|^2}{1-|\zeta|^2} \right )$.

The distance function is $d_D(\zeta_1,\zeta_2)=\cosh^{-1}\left ( 1+\frac{2|\zeta_1-\zeta_2|^2}{(1-|\zeta_1|^2)(1-|\zeta_2|^2)} \right )$

Equation of geodesic: $\frac{2\zeta}{1-|\zeta|^2}\eta + \frac{1+|\zeta|^2}{1-|\zeta|^2}z_0=0$.

Comment: What is your definition of the Poincare disk model?

Comment: @MoisheKohan It's the interior of the unit disk on a complex plane. $(x,y,z) \in H$ gets mapped to $\frac{x+iy}{1+z} \in D \subset \mathbb{C}$ by a projectivity. That's my definition.

Comment: This is not a meaningful definition. Where did you find it?

Comment: @MoisheKohan This is from my lecture note. My textbook, "Notes on Geometry" by E. Rees, says $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} | |z|<1\}$, where lines in $D$ is determined by the map $SV^{-1}:D \to L \to D$. Here $S : L \to D$ is a stereographic projection from $L$: the lower hemisphere of $S^2$, and $V : L \to D$ is defined by $(x,y,z) \mapsto x + iy$. However, in the post, I'll add my lecture note's definition in as much detail as I can because it differs from the textbook.

Comment: I see. So, in fact, your definition of the disk model is done via an explicit distance function. Do you already know that this distance function is invariant under Moebius transformations of the unit disk? If so, start by computing the conformal factor at the center of the disk and then argue that the conformal factor that you have is invariant under Moebius transformations of the unit disk. Incidentally, usually one starts with a Riemannian metric, then computes the distance function. And the last formula (the one you are trying to prove) you wrote in your question is wrong.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the hint! I assumed it should be the one; may I ask what the correct one is?

Comment: It is $ds_h= \frac{2}{1-|x|^2}ds_E$, where $ds$ denotes the length elements of the, respectively, hyperbolic and Euclidean metrics.